# Does `screen`'s `stuff` command use `stdin`?

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

[mpv](https://mpv.io/) is a media player that can be used interactively from the commmand line. This starts it in the terminal:

```
mpv path/to/playlist_file.m3u --no-audio-display
```

I can then press `>` to go to the next track and use [other interactive commands](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#interactive-control).

I can control it using `screen` as follows:

```
# start a screen session called "my_player"
screen -d -m -S my_player mpv path/to/playlist_file.m3u --no-audio-display
# next track
screen -S my_player -p 0 -X stuff ">"
# prev track
screen -S my_player -p 0 -X stuff "<"
# "end of text character" = control + c = terminate
screen -S my_player -p 0 -X stuff $'\003'
```

But what is screen's `stuff` command doing here? I would have guessed "sending input to standard in", but `echo ">" | mpv path/to/playlist_file.m3u` does not cause it to start up and immediately skip a track.

`man screen` says:

> Stuff the string string in the input buffer of the current  window. This  is like  the "paste" command but with much less overhead. You cannot paste large buffers with the "stuff" command. It is most useful for key bindings. See also "bindkey".

**By "the input buffer", does it mean standard input, or something else?**

(I ask because I want to control this program from Elixir via [`Port`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Port.html), which uses standard input and output, but so far my input seems to be ignored.)

Comment: `screen` provides a TTY interface (well, PTY -- a "pseudo-tty"). Thus, content it writes behaves just as terminal input would -- which *can* go to a program's inherited stdin, but can also go to `/dev/tty`. Thus, the `stuff` command can write to password prompts &c. that stdin intentionally bypasses.

Comment: If you want an easy way to get from stdin/stdout to a TTY-like interface *without* using `screen`, consider the program `unbuffer`, bundled with `expect`.

Comment: ...btw, note that `echo ">" | mpv ...` will have mpv seeing an EOF on stdin right after that `>` command; if one *is* getting commands from stdin, an EOF often is taken as an instruction to exit.

Comment: BTW, it might also be entertaining/informative/useful to look at what mpv does when started in a context where no TTY is available at all. Does it fall back to reading from stdin in that case, or does it just not accept new commands at all? (Very legitimate question -- without looking at its source I don't know either).